# Swift RegexBuilder new syntax 2 or more spaces

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-regexbuilder

Hi I'm trying to build a regular expression builder to detect 2 or more spaces or a tab, so (`let twoOrMoreSpacesOrTab = /\s{2,}|\t/`)

How to build this using a Regex Builder?

I tried this but its not 100% acurate:

```
ChoiceOf {
    OneOrMore("  ")
    One("\t")
}
```

The problem here is that is trying to match multiples of 2 white spaces, and I want to consume the whole thing.

Comment: Isn't "two or more", "one and one or more"? Like `One(" ")OneOrMore(" ")`? You could create a intermediary `TwoOrMore()` which would be one + oneOrMore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work.

```swift
let twoOrMoreSpacesOrTab = Regex {
    ChoiceOf {
        Repeat(2...) {
            One(.whitespace)
        }
        One("\t")
    }
}
```